# Error when adding User Libraries

Tags: java

I was using a user library in my program(Html Components).
I decided to copy this library to a new location inside the project, so I would be able to copy my project to another computer.
I've deleted the old library from the user library list. 
Now I'm trying to add the library from a new location.
When I add the external jars from the new location and press OK, i get an error on the library. When I expend a jar, i get all my fields as none.

I've tried to add another jar(that i haven't used before) from the same location and still have an error.

When I'm adding the library from its original location, it works.

Is there any limitation on the library path?
What can be the problem?

Now I've noticed that next to the jar file, next to the jar path, i get "(missing)"
In addition, works when i add just external jars. Still doesn't work when i try to create a user library.

Comment: I don't know, what is the problem?

Comment: I get the the red circled x error sign on the library, and on the jars in the library. All the fields in the jars(such as source attachment) are None

Comment: what IDE are you using? perhaps you need to clean your workspace or the project because there are artifacts of the old library import. just a wild guess...

Comment: Im using the juno release. Tried cleaning project and reseting enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Have a look at this link.

But basically I just added the library again, upgraded my eclipse, and then restarted it.

but have a look at these two links.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=201062

http://www.coderanch.com/t/105941/vc/Project-missing-required-library

Comment: IMO this is more suitable as comment.